# OpenGL (ES) Android -- Why does this glcolorpointer only color black?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a gradient, but first I just want to get the glcolorpointer working. If I use glColor4f(...) it draw colors correctly, but the glcolorpointer just draws black. Help please

```
gl11.glPushMatrix();
//gl11.glColor4f(RGBBorder[0], RGBBorder[1], RGBBorder[2], alpha);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerCube);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerCube);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);    
float colors[] = {.7f,.7f,.7f,.5f};
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer buff = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
buff.put(colors);
buff.position(0);               

gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, buff);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCube, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl11.glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you add color for one vertex only, and leave `buff` too small to handle all vertices you have. Using color buffer you're supposed to have, in this case, 4 floats per vertex, times 8 (assuming it's a cube you're drawing). It should be very much the same as introducing your vertex coordinates, even though I've never played around with `GL11.glBindBuffer`. This time with the difference it's a color value you're assigning for  each vertex.

[This tutorial](http://blog.uncle.se/2012/02/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-iv-adding-colors/) is very good read if you haven't done it already.

Comment: That was a problem, and I got it to work for a non VBO object. That VBO....... U should look into VBO, they increase performance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do that most definitely but will go on with GL10 first and check GL11/20 later on.